# Proving Positivity is Equivalent to $\langle v,v \rangle >0$ for some $v\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem $3$ of section $6.A$ in the textbook Linear Algebra Done Right is as follows

Suppose $\mathbb{F}= \mathbb{R}$ and $V \not = \{0\}$. Replace the positivity condition (which
states that $\langle v,v \rangle > 0$  $\forall v\in V$, $v\not= 0$) in the definition of an inner product
$(6.3)$ with the condition that $\langle v,v \rangle >0$ for some $v\in V$. Show that this
change in the definition does not change the set of functions from $V \times V$
to $\mathbb{R}$ that are inner products on $V$.

I assumed that this intends to point out that when the field is the real numbers, the condition positivity is equivalent to having at least one non-zero vector whose inner product with itself is positive.

If that is true, then since we can immediately show that any scalar multiple of $v$ also satisfies the positivity condition, the next step would be to prove that positivity holds for any non-zero vector $u$ that is not in the span $v$. The information that I notice is given are $\langle v,v \rangle$ and conjugate symmetry is now become commutativity. SO I reasoned I must somehow form an expression using $\langle v,v\rangle >0$ to show that $\langle u, u \rangle> 0$.

One approach I tried was to expand the expression
\begin{align*}
\langle v,v\rangle &= \langle u+(v-u) , u + (v-u)\rangle \\
 &= \langle u,u\rangle + \langle u , v-u\rangle + \langle v-u, u \rangle + \langle v-u, v-u \rangle \\
&= \langle u,u \rangle + 2\langle u,v-u \rangle - \langle u, v-u\rangle + \langle v,v-u\rangle \\
&= \langle u,u\rangle - \langle u+v, u-v \rangle >0
\end{align*}

In another exercise we proved that if $u$ and $v$ have the same norm, then $\langle u+v, u-v \rangle = 0$. So if could argue that I can choose $u$ in this way, I should be done. But if I'm not mistaken, I can't do this since I don't know that the norm induced by the inner product is well-defined anymore.

I would appreciate a hint on how to solve this problem. Is the idea to use an expression equivalent to $\langle v,v \rangle$ and expand using the properties of inner products to eventually show $\langle u, u \rangle >0$?

Comment: Typo? "replace the condition ... with the condition that $\langle v,v\rangle$ *>0*..."?  And then it's just for _some_ $v$? If that's the claim, I don't think it's right. For example, on $\mathbb R^2$, \langle (x,y), (x,y)\rangle=x^2-y^2$ has _some_ "positive" vectors, but certainly not _all_. Are you misreading the exercise, by chance?

Comment: It is certainly possible. I just rechecked that I copied the exercise correctly, so it's correct as typed. I made a pretty large assumption that the set of inner products being equal meant that the conditions are equivalent, which could be wrong and you are supposed to show that it just doesn't add any new functions which satisfy the other properties of inner products.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see where you were referring to the typo and fixed it, didn't notice at first glance. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Solution to problem $3$ of section $6.A$ in the textbook Linear Algebra Done Right is as follows:

The question is asking us to replace the **positivity** property "$\langle v, v\rangle \geq 0$ **for all** $v \in V$" with the following property: "**there exists** $v \in V$ such that $\langle v, v\rangle > 0$" and to show that this change in the definition does not change the set of functions from $V \times V$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which are inner products on $V$.
Note: all other properties including the **definiteness** property "$\langle v, v\rangle = 0$" iff $v = 0$" remain the same.

Solution:
With this change in positive property but not definiteness property, let's choose $u \in V$ such that $u \neq 0$ and $\langle u, u\rangle > 0$.
Let's *assume* that there exists $w \in V$ such that $w \neq 0$ and $\langle w, w\rangle < 0$.
Note: $w$ and $u$ are linearly independent (from the homogeneity property).
For convenience, let $\langle u, u\rangle = a^2$ and $\langle w, w\rangle = -b^2$ where $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Consider $f : t \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto tu + w$. None of the $f(t)$ are equal to $0$ due to $u$ and $w$ being linearly independent, yet we have:
$$\langle f(t), f(t)\rangle = \langle tu + w, tu + w\rangle = t^2 \langle u,u\rangle + 2t\langle u,w\rangle + \langle w, w\rangle = t^2a^2 + 2t\langle u,w\rangle - b^2$$
Therefore:
$$\langle f(t), f(t)\rangle = 0 \Leftrightarrow t^2a^2 +2t\langle u,w\rangle - b^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow t = \frac{-\langle u,w\rangle \pm \sqrt{\langle u,w\rangle^2 - a^2b^2}}{a^2}$$
Hence there are two values of $t$ such that $f(t) \neq 0$ yet $\langle f(t), f(t)\rangle$, **which contradicts the definiteness property**.
Thus, if we assume that "there exists $v$ such that $\langle v,v\rangle > 0$" while all the other properties remain unchanged, then we are forced to conclude that "$\langle v, v\rangle \geq 0$ for all $v \in V$".
In other words, the set of functions from $V \times V$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which are inner products on $V$ does not change.

Comment: I know it's been two years, but someone should have told you that images are frowned upon for technical reasons (searchability for example) as well as accessibility reasons (some users use screen readers). Too bad because the answer itself is very good in my opinion, it just needed to be written and MathJax'd.

Comment: As for some small precisions in regards to the answer itself: $t$ such that $f(t)$ (your $z$ originally, I took a few liberties while transcribing the image but not too many) could be unique if it's a double root, but what matters is that there is at least one such $t$ so that's fine, and; you forgot the other direction, you showed that one set of inner products for one definition is included in the set of inner products for the second definition but forgot to show the other inclusion, although is definitely much easier since it's a straightforward use of positivity and definiteness.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show two things. First that the new condition implies the positivity condition in a real vector space and the converse.

To show that the new condition implies the positivity condition fix a $w \in V$ and then show that $\langle w,w \rangle \ \geq 0$.

You may find it useful to consider two cases: $w = \lambda v$ for some $v\in V$ and $w \neq \lambda v$ for all $v \in V$