# Exercise $3$, Section $6.A$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products

Exercise: Suppose $F = R$ and $V \ne  \{0\}$. Replace the positivity condition (which states that $\langle v, v\rangle \ge 0$ for all $v \in V$ ) in the definition of an inner product $(6.3)$ with the condition that $\langle v, v \rangle > 0$ for some $v \in V$. Show that this change in the definition does not change the set of functions from $V \times V$ to $R$ that are inner products on $V$.

Proof: Let $A$ denote the set of all inner products on $V$ with the condition that $\langle v, v\rangle \ge 0$ for all $v\in V$. Let $B$ denote the set of all inner products on $V$ with the condition that $\langle v, v\rangle > 0$ for some $v\in V$.

Let $f \in A$(denoted by $\langle , \rangle$). Given that $f$ is an inner product, we know that $\langle v, v\rangle = 0$ if and only if $v=0$ and $\langle v , v\rangle \ge 0$ for all $v$. Given that $V\ne \{0\}$, there exists a non zero vector $v\in V$ such that $\langle v, v\rangle > 0$. Thus, $f \in B$.

Is this proof correct?

Edit: I have added a picture of how an inner product is defined in the book.
[image]

Comment: Are you setting $f := \langle\,\rangle$?

Comment: @AlvinL Yes. I should add that in.

Comment: Can you restate the positivity definition? I don't think $\langle 0,0\rangle \geq 0$ is correct.

Comment: You showed that $A \subset B$, but what the exercise wants you to prove is $A = B$ presumably.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed Thanks for pointing that out. Just fixed it!

Comment: I don't think $A=B$ is true. Where is this exercise from?

Comment: @BrunoB That was what I was gonna do. But for some reason, I convinced myself that that was wrong. I will try and do that now.

Comment: @geetha290krm From Linear algebra done right. It's exercise 3 from section 6.A.

Comment: I added "presumably" because I'm not sure myself if it's true, but that's what the exercise is saying.

Comment: I heavily advise that you look at the definition of the inner product that Axler gives, because positivity and definiteness are separated. Incidentally once you know this, the proof follows the same lines on what you've written. (Ideally you should have written the definition because without definiteness this equivalence is not true.)

Comment: @AlvinL Definiteness: there's still $\langle v, v\rangle = 0$ iff $v = 0$. Giving the definition would get rid of ambiguities I guess.

Comment: @AlvinL I said that there exists one non zero vector $v$ such that $\langle v, v\rangle > 0$. This comes from the hypothesis that $V\ne \{0\}$ and the hypothesis that $f$ is an inner product on $V$ in the usual sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving Positivity is Equivalent to $\langle v,v \rangle > 0$ for some $v\in V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898222/proving-positivity-is-equivalent-to-langle-v-v-rangle-0-for-some-v-in-v)

Answer (score 3):

[Original answer was wrong and has been deleted.  Here is an argument that hopefully works.]

You have only proved it in one direction.  For the reverse direction, we will make a continuity argument.  I will avoid appealing to vector space topologies in case you haven't been exposed to that notion - advanced readers might notice you can clean this up a bit if you know some facts about them.

Suppose $f=\langle,\rangle\in B$, let $v\in V$ satisfy $\langle v,v\rangle >0$, and suppose by contradiction that $f\notin A$, i.e., $\langle w,w\rangle<0$ for some $w\in V$. Since every scalar multiple $\lambda v$ of $v$ satisfies $\langle \lambda v,\lambda v\rangle =|\lambda|^2 \langle v,v\rangle>0$, $w$ is not in the span of $v$, so the line $\gamma(t)=(1-t)v+tw$ joining $v$ to $w$ does not intersect $0$.

From the additivity and homogeneity and symmetry axioms we have that $\langle,\rangle$ is linear in each variable, whereby $t\mapsto \langle \gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle$ is continuous (in fact quadratic in $t$), with $$\langle \gamma(0),\gamma(0)\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle>0$$ and $$\langle \gamma(1),\gamma(1)\rangle = \langle w,w\rangle<0\text{,}$$
so by the intermediate value theorem $\langle \gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle=0$ for some $t$, contradicting definiteness since $\gamma$ does not pass through $0$.

[Remark: Observe that this argument works over $\mathbb C$ as well, since $t\mapsto \langle \gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle$ still maps $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ by the conjugate symmetry property.]

Comment: Not sure how your $-\langle v, w \rangle$ turns into a $\langle v, w \rangle$. I am getting $\langle v - w, v - w \rangle = - 2 \langle v, w \rangle$. (Working over $\mathbf{R}$.)

Comment: Yeach I screwed up, my apologize, will delete this.

Answer (score 2):

Conversely, let $\langle v,v \rangle > 0$ for some $v\neq 0$ and let $w\in V$. By conjugacy $\langle w,w\rangle$ is real.

Assume for a contradiction $\langle w,w \rangle < 0$. Scale respectively such that $\langle v,v\rangle = 1$ and $\langle w,w\rangle = -1$.  On the one hand, we have for all $\lambda\in \mathbb R =F$ that
$$\begin{align*} \langle \lambda v+ w, \lambda v+ w\rangle &= \lambda ^2 + 2 \langle v,w\rangle\lambda -1. \end{align*}$$
The discriminant $4\langle v,w \rangle ^2 +4 >0$ so there are two distinct zeros $\lambda _1\neq \lambda _2$. On the other hand
$$ \langle \lambda _1v + w, \lambda _1v+w\rangle = \langle \lambda _2v+w,\lambda _2v+w\rangle = 0, $$
which implies $\lambda_1v+w = \lambda _2v+w = 0$ due to the definite property, hence $(\lambda _1-\lambda _2)v = 0$. Since $v\neq 0$ we must have $\lambda _1=\lambda _2$, a contradiction. So we must conclude that $\langle w,w\rangle \geqslant 0$.

---

If $F=\mathbb C$, then
$$ \langle \lambda v +w,\lambda v+w\rangle = |\lambda|^2 + 2\left (\mathrm{Re}\langle v,w\rangle\right ) \lambda -1,\quad \lambda\in\mathbb C. $$
It suffices to find two distinct zeros and repeat the argument above.

Comment: Initial version was gibberish, corrected that now, hopefully.